# onActivityResult crashing app kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a basic meme generator and having issues returning the changed text to the main activity. As of now when I run the app, I am able to click the edit icon in the corner and it takes me to the selectionScreen activity. From here you can edit the text for the top and bottom values. Also displayed is the url of the image from mainActivity. This is intended to function in a way that will allow users to enter their own url and retrieve an image they want to apply text to but I am nowhere close to tackling that issue yet. When the user clicks the save icon it is supposed to return the changed text and apply that to the image displayed. As of now it just crashes my app. It allows navigation back to mainActivity if I comment out my two values in onActivityResult but, obviously, with no changes applied.

code is as follows:
MainActivity:

```
package com.example.willo.memegene
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.*
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_selection_screen.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val url = 
"http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/18/15/324D202500000578-3498922-
image-a-33_1458315465874.jpg"

       Picasso.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .into(imageView)
        edit.setOnClickListener{

            val intent = Intent(this, SelectionScreen::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("When nothing works", (topText.text.toString()))
                putExtra("And then it all works", 
(bottomText.text.toString()))
                putExtra("URL", url )
            }

            startActivityForResult(intent,1)
        }






   }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: 
Intent?) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != 
null){

            val returnedTop = intent.getStringExtra("Back to main")
            topText.setText(returnedTop)

            val returnedBottom = intent.getStringExtra("Off with you")
            bottomText.setText(returnedBottom)



        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.user_options, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)

    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {


        Builder(this)

                .setTitle("About")
                .setMessage(" Name: MemeGene \n Author: Kenneth Willoughby 
\n " +
                        "Version: 1.0")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .show()
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }


}
```

SelectionScreen activity:

```
package com.example.willo.memegene

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_selection_screen.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_selection_screen.*

class SelectionScreen : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection_screen)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

       val url = 
"http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/18/15/324D202500000578-3498922-
image-a-33_1458315465874.jpg"

        //Picasso.with(this)
               //.load(url)
             // .into(imageView2)

        val topText = intent.getStringExtra("When nothing works")
            topText2.setText(topText)

        val bottomText = intent.getStringExtra("And then it all works")
            bottomText2.setText(bottomText)

        val link = intent.getStringExtra("URL")
            url2.setText(link)


        save.setOnClickListener{
            val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply{
                putExtra("Back to main", topText2.text.toString())
                putExtra("Off with you", bottomText2.text.toString())
                putExtra("URL Again", url2.text.toString())

            }

            val returnIntent = this.intent
            returnIntent.putExtra("Results",i)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
            finish()
        }

        }

    }
```

****EDIT****

I fixed the issue crashing, however, now when the user selects the save widget it takes them back to the MainActivity.kt but with no text. The original hard coded text is gone so I know that it is returning something to make the original data go away. What I can't figure out is why I can't get it to pass back text that is entered from SelectionScreen.kt

Comment: please post stack information

Comment: Edited post to include logcat

Comment: Your log doesn't mention the crash cause. Please find the part with FATAL EXCEPTION followed by exception trace.

Comment: I found the cause of the crash. Had to modify topText to topText.setText(returnedTop) and remove .toString(). Same for bottomText.

Comment: Added Edit to show new issue once crash was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting intent into another one and expecting the primitive results from the first one.

```
 val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply{
            putExtra("Back to main", topText2.text.toString())
            putExtra("Off with you", bottomText2.text.toString())
            putExtra("URL Again", url2.text.toString())

        }
```

change below to

```
        val returnIntent = this.intent
        returnIntent.putExtra("Results",i)
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
        finish()
```

this one

```
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i)
        finish()
```

this should give you the desired results.

Comment: Still nothing. Thanks though, this really helped me to look at what exactly is happening with the intents. It seems to me the intent is working in that it will pass empty strings and set them to top and bottom text and the fields are empty when you go to edit the now empty meme.